# WebSQL SELECT Statment failing to get result set

Tags: javascript, html

Im using WebSQL to write a offline application mainly for iOS and for Android that supports WebSQL spec (obvs until iOS 8 is out iOS doesn't support IndexedDB).

I have successfully created 4 tables, two of which will have about 100 rows of data each. The data is inserted into these two different tables using two functions which run asynchronously. However, when I run a SELECT statement I get a result however it seems the result has an error manifested within it; please see below.

SQLResultSet {rowsAffected: 0, rows: SQLResultSetRowList}insertId: [Exception: DOMException: Failed to read the 'insertId' property from 'SQLResultSet': The query didn't result in any rows being added.]rows: SQLResultSetRowListrowsAffected: 0__proto__: SQLResultSet

If anyone could help explain what this error means as I cant seem to find anything on the net or in the doc's for it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Any attempt to access the insertId property of the SQLResultSet when no rows were added will throw this error.

Because you are running a SELECT query this is the behaviour I would expect.

Personally I would prefer if it returned null in this case, but that does not appear to be the case.